# Change installation directory of a SharePoint 2007 post install

Tags: 2007, installation

I have a problematic customer who I thought was doing the right thing by installing it on a particular volume.. anyway apprarently he wants to move the SharePoint installation directories to another volume.

Other than re-installing the product, and probably having to go through hell in doing that is there a way to accomplish this. I can see that there is an XML file that you can specify prior to installing but my guess is there are refrences to the path littered throught the registry and config DB?

Comment: check this similar question that would be helpful - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32256/sharepoint-installation-location/32263#32263

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really the only way to achieve this is to remove the WFE reinstall SharePoint and specify the correct location, then reconnect the SharePoint server to the databases. Probably easier just to stand up a new VM and make that the primary SharePoint server if truth be told.